# What is the difference between these crawled title properties?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2013, what is the difference between these title crawled properties when I am working with Word Documents?

- MetadataExtractorTitle
- Office:2
- ows_BaseName
- Title
- Basic:displaytitle
- Basic:10
- Basic:9

I can't find a single source online that gives a clear definition on how each of these items relate to a Word Document.  I do see under Site Settings -> Search Schema in SharePoint 2013, that I can re-order these title items.  But I would like to know what I am actually pushing to the top first with a clear understanding on what it does / pull.

Thanks

Comment: This MSDN blog discusses it in detail: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2013/10/31/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is however a hidden mechanism present in SharePoint 2013 which is called  title metadata extraction which overwrite the “Title” managed property with a value SharePoint extracts from parts of Word and PowerPoint documents.

You can get more detailed information from [here](http://jopx.blogspot.in/2014/01/understanding-title-information-shown.html)

References:

- [Mystery Solved – Crawled Properties in SharePoint (Part 4)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/anneste/archive/2008/11/25/mystery-solved-crawled-properties-in-sharepoint-part-4.aspx)  - explains the Office crawled property category
- [Mystery Solved – Crawled Properties in SharePoint (Part 2)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/anneste/archive/2008/11/25/mystery-solved-crawled-properties-in-sharepoint-part-2.aspx) – explains the Baisc crawled property category
- [Overview of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx)
- [Show more relevant Titles in search results in SharePoint 2013 plus some other improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2013/10/31/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements.aspx)